# Facebook Album Creation php

Tags: php

When I issue the following post command to create the album, nothing is created.

```
    $album_url="https://graph.facebook.com/".$fanpage_id."/albums?"
    . "name=" . urlencode($album_name)
    . "&message=" . urlencode($album_description)
    . "&method=POST"
    . "&access_token=" . $fanpage_token; 
    file_get_contents($graph_url);
```

However, the album can be created with the below hard code. Something wrong in the above post command?

```
   $album_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/xxx/albums?name=%22album%20php%20%20name%22&message=%22Album%20php%20%20description%22&method=POST&access_token=xx;
   file_get_contents($album_url);
```

Comment: Have you try comparing both URLs? Are they exactly the same?

Comment: you call file_get_contents($album_url); but assign the url to $graph_url ?

Comment: also try echo $graph_url;

Comment: Thanks your advice. When I output the $album_url, it returns:      https:// graph.facebook.com/231794566957447/albums?name=Pet+GoHome+Tung+Album&message=Tung+Album+description&method=POST&access_token=xxx   Why?

Comment: TobSpr is correct. I assign the url incorrectly. Thanks!!